# How can I set the LIB environment variable inside a csproj file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm operating on a system where the environment variable `LIB` is set to "--must-override--". I cannot change the value of the variable on the system itself.

In Visual Studio, the LIB variable is checked during compilation. Because it's set to a junk value, I get a warning in the build:

> Invalid search path '--must-override--' specified in 'LIB environment variable' -- 'The system cannot find the path specified.

I'd like to get rid of this warning. To do so, I need to override the value of the `LIB` environment variable that VS uses, either to NULL or to some value pointing to a real path.

Since I can't change the value of the variable in the environment, I need to do it within the csproj file itself. I've tried setting it in a property group to no avail:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Lib></Lib>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Any ideas on how this variable can be set? Or if it's even possible?

Comment: It is not very clear which project has that variable and what is the goal in general. Can you put some more details?

Comment: @BiserC I've edited the question to try to make it more clear.

Comment: SO users tend to suffer from the strangest self-inflicted wounds.  The environment variable is only relevant for C++ projects.  A simple workaround is to just create the "--must-override--" directory in your project folder.

Comment: @HansPassant I am in awe; that is a *fantastic* answer. :)

Comment: @HansPassant Agreed - and I can verify that it gets rid of the warning, even if it's a bit of a hack :)

Answer (score 1):

You can mangle it in using the `Exec` Task, or you can write your own `Task` to set them - here's the "Let's mangle away with Exec" route:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- 
      need the CData since this blob is just going to
      be embedded in a mini batch file by studio/msbuild
    -->
    <LibSetter><![CDATA[
set Lib=C:\Foo\Bar\Baz
set AnyOtherEnvVariable=Hello!
]]></LibSetter>
</PropertyGroup>

<Exec Command="$(LibSetter)" />
```

EDIT: 
So I just threw this csproj together with the basics - I've confirmed they do set properly when I run them - I've added in the inline-Task approach as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <UsingTask 
        TaskName="EnvVarSet" 
        TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" 
        AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
        <ParameterGroup>
          <VarName ParameterType="System.String" Required="true"/>
          <VarValue ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
        </ParameterGroup>
        <Task>
            <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
                <![CDATA[
                    Console.WriteLine("Setting var name {0} to {1}...", VarName, VarValue);
                    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(VarName, VarValue);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", VarName, VarValue);
                ]]>
            </Code>
        </Task>
    </UsingTask>

    <Target Name="ThingThatNeedsEnvironmentVars">
        <CallTarget Targets="FiddleWithEnvironmentVars"/>
        <Message Text="LIB environment var is now: $([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('LIB'))"/>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="FiddleWithEnvironmentVars">
        <Message Text="LIB environment var is now: $([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('LIB'))"/>
        <EnvVarSet VarName="LIB" VarValue="C:\temp"/>
        <Message Text="LIB environment var is now: $([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('LIB'))"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me - I tried verifying by putting `<Message Text="$(LIB)" />` immediately before and after the Exec statement, and the value remains unchanged.

Comment: @AndyMagee Well, you want to echo the environment variable value of LIB, right? put in a similar `Exec` but instead of `set...`, have it `echo %LIB%`

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171459(v=vs.110).aspx), environment variables should be directly accessible the way I tried to use `$(LIB)` above. Either way, even when using `echo %LIB%`, the value doesn't get set. It still echoes the original value.

Comment: Huh...strange. Oh well, I'll add in the alternatives in the answer.